# Create JSON with 2 large data sets?

Tags: json, excel, dictionary, join, jq

I have 2 huge sets of numbers in columns 1 and 2 in an excel sheet. I want to pair my first column with my second column to create a JSON file like this link here - https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/data/data3.json,
something like

```
[{"0500000US33009": 51289.0, "0500000US38041": 46793.0, "0500000US38043": 39857.0}]
```

if I had just the numbers 0500000US33009, 0500000US38041, and 0500000US38043 in column 1 and 51289.0, 46793.0, and 39857.0 in column 2. How might I do this, and make sure that the resulting JSON has quotes around the "0500000US33009"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> if I had just the numbers ...

The following assumes that the first two columns have been extracted into a CSV or TSV file, e.g.

```
0500000US33009,51289.0
0500000US38041,46793.0
0500000US38043,39857.0
```

With the input data in this format, it would of course be very easy to use your favorite text-processing tool to create a JSON dictionary.

Assuming a simple CSV format as above, the data could also be converted into a JSON dictionary using an invocation along the lines of:

```
jq -Rn 'reduce inputs as $in ({}; 
  . + ($in|split(",")|{(.[0]): .[1] |  tonumber}))'
```

Using jq 1.6 or earlier, this would produce:

```
{
  "0500000US33009": 51289,
  "0500000US38041": 46793,
  "0500000US38043": 39857
}
```

The change in format of the numeric values is the result of a conversion to IEEE 754 64-bit numbers, and can be avoided by using a more recent version of jq.  Using the current "master" version, the result would be:

```
{
  "0500000US33009": 51289.0,
  "0500000US38041": 46793.0,
  "0500000US38043": 39857.0
}
```

So if you're stuck with jq 1.6 or earlier and require the explicit decimal point, you might want to consider omitting `|tonumber` in the above program, and add a post-processing step if and as required.

### Some words of caution

1. The jq solution above assumes there are no collisions (one key having more than one value), or rather, that if there are any collisions, then the last key-value pair should prevail.
2. If any of the values in the second column cannot be represented with sufficient accuracy as IEEE 754 64-bit numbers, then a significantly different strategy may be warranted.
3. If the number of rows is indeed very large (e.g. in the billions), then the wisdom of constructing a single ginormous JSON dictionary might be worth reconsidering.

Comment: thanks so much for your response. I was just wondering, where do I put in the file name/location to the terminal? I have my excel sheet with 2 columns, but where do I put the file in the code above so that the terminal knows which excel sheet to parse?

Comment: You would have to extract the two columns from the Excel spreadsheet into a CSV or TSV file, say cols.csv; then you could run: jq -Rn -f program.jq cols.csv

Comment: Sorry - I didn't understand - how did "program.jq" show up? How do I set your previous code, "'reduce inputs as $in ({}; 
  . + ($in|split(",")|{(.[0]): .[1]  tonumber}))'" to program.jq? Thanks!

Comment: I got ". + ($in|split(",")|{(.[0]): .[1]  tonumber}))'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting '$' or '[' or '{' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 2:" after trying your suggested answer.

Comment: Somehow the | before tonumber went missing.